# AWS Lambda: What options can I use to migrate my Nest project NODE 14 to Lambda NODE 20?

Tags: aws-lambda, nestjs, serverless-framework

The project has been developed in Node.js 14 using NestJS, and the Serverless framework (serverless-plugin-optimize) is used to deploy it to an AWS Lambda service. It had been running without any issues; however, AWS, upon withdrawing support, requests an update to Node.js version 20, which is causing problems when deploying it with the Serverless framework.

```
Error: Cannot read file .... due to: EMFILE: too many open files, open
```